# jq flattening JSON arrays

Tags: json, jq

This

```
echo '{"a":[{"b":[{"c":"xxx"}]},{"b":[{"c":"yyy"},{"c":"zzz"}]}]}' |
    jq '.a[].b | map({"c": .c})'
```

produces this:

```
[
  {
    "c": "xxx"
  }
]
[
  {
    "c": "yyy"
  },
  {
    "c": "zzz"
  }
]
```

How do I get a single output array like:

```
[
  {
    "c": "xxx"
  },
  {
    "c": "yyy"
  },
  {
    "c": "zzz"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
jq '[{"c":(.a[].b[].c)}]' file.json
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ jq [.[][][][]] <<< "$JSON"
[
  {
    "c": "xxx"
  },
  {
    "c": "yyy"
  },
  {
    "c": "zzz"
  }
]
```

OR:

```
$ jq '[.. | select(has("c")?)]' <<< "$JSON"
[
  {
    "c": "xxx"
  },
  {
    "c": "yyy"
  },
  {
    "c": "zzz"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

This does it:

```
jq '[ .a[][][] ]'
```